# Flutter - Create list and 'addAll' in same instruction

Tags: arrays, arraylist, flutter

I'm trying to search a element in the  array. When get  it i need to append some element of the end of the array.

I try similar to this.

```
List dataModelo = allMakers //THIS IS THE MAIN ARRRAY
                                    .where((modelo) =>
                                        modelo["fabricante"] ==
                                        fabricante["fabricante"])
                                    .toList()
                                    .addAll([
                                  {
                                    "id": 0,
                                    "fabricante":
                                        'Test,
                                    "modelo":
                                        'Test'
                                  }
                                ]);
```

But return

> The expression here has a type of 'void', and therefore cannot be
>   used.

So anybody know how can i do that?

**SOLUTION**:

```
 dataModelo = allMakers
                                .where((modelo) =>
                                    modelo["fabricante"] ==
                                    fabricante["fabricante"])
                                .followedBy([
                              {
                                "id": 0,
                                "fabricante":
                                   'TEXT',
                                "modelo":
                                    'TEXT'
                              }
                            ]).toList();
```

Answer (score 5):

Use [cascade notation](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#cascade-notation-) after the `.where(/**/).toList()` part.

e.g.

```dart
final arr = [1, 2, 3];
print(arr.where((a) => a > 2).toList()
         ..addAll([ 4, 5 ])); // returns [3, 4, 5]
```

In other words, adding another `.` to your `.addAll` part should do the trick.

Comment: I found the solution.